# Protecting suspension bushings from oil-related damage

Tags: suspension, bushing

Bit of an oddball question.

My car refuses to track straight on any road that isn't perfectly flat & level, among other problems; I've narrowed the problem down to the existing control arm bushings. I am planning on buying preloaded control arms with rubber bushings (not any kind of urethane-type material) and ball joints already installed to save myself some trouble.

The only problem here, however, is that one out of the four existing worn bushings is particularly damaged because of several oil & power steering fluid leaks. While I would, in theory, like to get the leaks fixed, all the parts & supplies involved are close to $1,000 and the labor involved would require me to leave my only mode of transport inoperative for several days - not an option; and my main concern is making sure my vehicle is safe to drive down the road.

Thus my question - when installing brand new rubber suspension bushings, is there any way I can protect them from being damaged from existing (or future) oil leaks?

Comment: If you continue to pour oil on them then NO.

Comment: Get some industrial rubber sheeting, cut some squares, then use zip-ties to hang the squares between the bushings and the oil source.